# What is the device-width of the Samsung Galaxy Note II?

Tags: android, mobile, browser, web, device-width

I cannot find the real device-width of the Samsung Galaxy Note II for web browsers, I found 3 different values as 320px, 480px and 640px but I'm not able to know which is the correct one.

By the way I found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density) the list of displays by pixel density but no device-width...

Edit:
I'm looking for the web device-width declared in the mobile browser (viewport).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey i have a note 2 and i got the width from DisplayMetrics and it says it is 720 pixels and height is 1280 pixels

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the "web" device-width, could you check this link from Chrome http://goo.gl/b0Otl please? There will be an alert telling you what's the size.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this.?

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

They are

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find it out programmatically just check out this question.
[Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

If not, you could ask over here: https://android.stackexchange.com/